# Is it right to use "size-one" as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, hyphens, compounds

When talking about an options menu (composed of menu items) of only one option, can I say "one size menu" or "one-sized menu"?

Otherwise, how can I precede the noun *menu* with an adjective that denotes this quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for

> a single item menu

It's still not an adjective (well, *single* is, but it modifies *item*), but you can use [nouns as adjectives](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm) in English.